# Spring: Service Class with @Service annotation gets "required bean of type 'abcService' could not be found"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, spring-batch

I have a spring batch application in which the writer has an @Autowired field (it is a service class). When running tests for the writer step, I am met with the error:

```
Field batchTrackingService in com.ally.cr.miscinfo.batch.writer.AdvantageClientItemWriter required a bean of type 'com.test.miscinfo.service.TestService' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.test.miscinfo.service.batchTrackingService ' in your configuration.
```

I've looked at a few answers to related questions, and most of them are caused by the fact that the class being injected has not been annotated with @Component, @Service, @Repository, etc. However mine is. I also read questions where the supposed solution was to add the @ComponentScan() annotation to the Main class of my application. After trying this, it gave the same error. Can someone please help me? Any help is appreciated.

Here are the relevant classes:

Main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.test.miscinfo.repository")
@EntityScan("com.test.miscinfo.entity")
@ComponentScan("com.test.miscinfo.service")
public class MiscInfoServiceApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MiscInfoServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Writer class:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class AdvantageClientItemWriter implements ItemWriter<MiscInfo> {
  @Autowired private AdvantageClientConfig advantageClientConfig;
  @Autowired WebClient advantageClientWebClient;

  @Autowired private BatchTrackingService batchTrackingService;


  @Override
  public void write(List<? extends MiscInfo> miscInfos) throws Exception {
     /* some call to a method in the injected service */ 
  }

}
```

Service class:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
@Transactional
@Service
public class BatchTrackingService {
  public void someMethod() {}
}
```

Please let me know if I am missing relevant info.

**EDIT:**

Adding test method:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(value = AdvantageClientConfig.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { AdvantageClientItemWriter.class })
public class AdvantageClientItemWriterTest {
  @MockBean RestTemplate advantageClientRestTemplate;
  @MockBean WebClient advantageWebClient;
  WebClient.RequestBodyUriSpec requestBodyUriSpec = mock(WebClient.RequestBodyUriSpec.class);
  WebClient.RequestBodySpec requestBodySpec = mock(WebClient.RequestBodySpec.class);
  WebClient.ResponseSpec responseSpec = mock(WebClient.ResponseSpec.class);
  WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec requestHeadersSpec = mock(WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec.class);
  @Autowired AdvantageClientConfig advantageClientConfig;
  @Autowired AdvantageClientItemWriter advantageClientItemWriter;

  ArgumentCaptor<String> uriCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
  ArgumentCaptor<MediaType> mediaTypeCaptor= ArgumentCaptor.forClass(MediaType.class);
  ArgumentCaptor<String> headerNameCaptor= ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
  ArgumentCaptor<String> headerValueCaptor= ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
  ArgumentCaptor<String> bodyCaptor= ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
  private MemoryAppender memoryAppender;

  @BeforeEach
  public void init(){

    Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger("com.test");
    memoryAppender = new MemoryAppender();
    memoryAppender.setContext((LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory());
    logger.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
    logger.addAppender(memoryAppender);
    memoryAppender.start();
  }

  @Test
  public void successfulAdvantageClientWrite() throws Exception {
    setupMockReturns();
    when(responseSpec.toBodilessEntity()).thenReturn(Mono.just(new ResponseEntity(null, HttpStatus.OK)));

    List<MiscInfo> miscInfos = new ArrayList<>();
    final MiscInfo miscInfo = createMiscInfo1();
    miscInfos.add(miscInfo);

    advantageClientItemWriter.write(miscInfos);
    Assertions.assertEquals(advantageClientConfig.getEndpoint(), uriCaptor.getValue());
    Assertions.assertEquals(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, mediaTypeCaptor.getValue());
    Assertions.assertEquals( advantageClientConfig.getHeaderName(), headerNameCaptor.getValue());
    Assertions.assertEquals(advantageClientConfig.getApiKey(), headerValueCaptor.getValue());
    Assertions.assertEquals(new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(miscInfos), bodyCaptor.getValue());
    assertThat(memoryAppender.search("Write to Advantage status: ", Level.DEBUG).size()).isEqualTo(1);
  }
}
```

Comment: you have this error on Unit test? can you post it?

Comment: @PaulMarcelinBejan Added the test class and method

Comment: looks your component scan issue try without component scan com.ally.cr.miscinfo.batch.writer.AdvantageClientItemWriter

Answer (score 0):

This error means that Spring is trying to autowire of bean of type `BatchTrackingService` in your `AdvantageClientItemWriter` but it could not find one in the application context. In other words, your test context does not contain a bean definition of type `BatchTrackingService`, which could be due to one of the following causes:

- Either the configuration class that defines that bean is not imported in the test class (in `@ContextConfiguration(classes = { AdvantageClientItemWriter.class })`
- or the class of that bean is not in the package that is scanned by Spring (Boot).

Make sure that:

1. the class `public class BatchTrackingService {}` is defined in the package referenced in `@ComponentScan("com.test.miscinfo.service")`
2. the `@ContextConfiguration` annotation imports the class of that bean (something like `@ContextConfiguration(classes = { AdvantageClientItemWriter.class, BatchTrackingService.class })`, or that it imports a configuration class which defines an instance of that bean.